# Using a random pivot in Quicksort, Java

Tags: java, quicksort

My code almost works correctly, giving me a nearly sorted outdata. 
The `cmp(i,j)` method returns a negative value `if i < j` and a positive `if j > i`.

**Code:**

```
public void sort(){ 
    sortQuick(0, getElementCount()-1);
}
public void sortQuick (int first, int last){
    // pivot tilldelas ett värde mellan noll och antal element i vektorn.
    final Random random = new Random();
    System.out.println(("Last: " + last + ", first : " + first));
    int up = first;                          
    int down = last; 

    int pivot = random.nextInt(last-first) + first;
    System.out.println(pivot);                          
    while (up < down ) {

        while (cmp(up,pivot) < 0) {
            up++;
        }
        while (cmp(down,pivot) > 0) {
            down--;
        }
        if (up <= down) {
            swap(up,down);
            up++;
            down--;
        }
    }
    if (down > first) {
        sortQuick(first, down);
    }
    if (last > up) {
        sortQuick(up, last);
    }
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Where is the data stored?  I don't see any mention of an array or list?

Comment: compare your code with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065910/stuck-in-a-simple-quick-sort-implementation-with-random-pivot?rq=1

Comment: Do you have a test input for which your sort algorithm produces only a "nearly" sorted output?

Comment: Tyler: the data is stored in other classes, which this class calls on.

Graham: Guess what I did ;). Still doesn't work.

Yes I do. If I use that it becomes totally sorted. Also, if I run quicksort twice (sometimes trice) on the vector of number I want to sort, it will get perfectly sorted.

Comment: I have run a couple of test cases and always the result was nicely sorted. Perhaps the fault is not in this code but in cmp/swap?

Comment: Cmp and swap works fine, using them for tons of other sorters implemented. Have you run it with really big data sets?

Comment: `The cmp(i,j) method returns a negative value if i < j and a positive if j > i.` - What if they're equal?  - - Also wouldn't removing the `-1` from this `sortQuick(0, getElementCount()-1);` help?

Comment: If theyre equal, it returns 0. Would I need that?
I am sorting a vector containing getElementCount() number of values. They are stored in position 0 to position getElementCount()-1.

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only store the index of the pivot element and not the actual value.

If later in the algorithm, `up` (or `down`) happen to reach the value `pivot` and are subject to a swap, then value at index `pivot` changes. Subsequent comparisons are hence against a different pivot elements.

Remember the pivot value and make all comparisons against it, like in:

```
int pivotIndex = random.nextInt(last-first) + first;
int pivotValue = getValueAt(pivotIndex);

while (up < down ) {

    while (getValueAt(up) < pivotValue) {
        up++;
    }
    while (getValueAt(down) > pivotValue) {
        down--;
    }
    if (up <= down) {
        swap(up,down);
        up++;
        down--;
    }
```

*Alternatively*, you could update the pivot index when swapping:

```
    if (up <= down) {
        swap(up,down);
        if(pivot == up) { pivot = down; }
        else if(pivot == down) { pivot = up; }
        up++;
        down--;
    }
```

Comment: Alright.. I don't really understand how to implement that though. Could you give me a code example?

Comment: Ok, I enriched my answer to provide you with some ideas.

Comment: It works! You're the man, man! If I knew how to, I'd uprep you!